# Map field values in a view based on returned values in the underlying table T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need a way, within a `SELECT` statement, to either map the data from a column called `Content` or rename the column name (aka ALIASING) a column called `dbo.table.Content` based on the character value of a different column `dbo.table.VersionName` such that **IF** `dbo.table.VersionName.value` = `XYZABC` **THEN** the column `dbo.table.Content` alias will display as `XYZABC_Content` for that row in the resultset.

**IF** the column `dbo.table.VersionName.value` = `ABCXYZ` **THEN** the alias for the `dbo.table.Content` column should display `ABCXYZ_Content` Additionally **IF** the alias for the `dbo.table.Content` column is XYZABC_Content and it is populated with data then the column alias `ABCXYZ_Content` should be `NULL`

What I have tried so far:

```
CREATE VIEW schema.dtvViewName
AS
    DECLARE @intvalue int = 2
    SELECT 
        field1,
        field2,
        CASE VersionName
           WHEN 'XYZABC' THEN Content 
           WHEN 'ABCXYZ' THEN Content 
        END as [XYZABC_Content],
        CASE VersionName
           WHEN '123ABC' THEN Content 
        END as [123ABC_Content],
        CASE VersionName
           WHEN '567ABC' THEN Content 
        END as [567ABC_Content],
        CASE VersionName
           WHEN 'XYZABC' THEN ChangeType
           WHEN 'ABCXYZ' THEN ChangeType 
        END as [XYZABC_ChangeType],
        ...
        CASE field3 
           WHEN '567ABC' THEN ChangeTime 
        END as [567ABC_ChangeTime]
    FROM 
        dbo.table
    WHERE 
        batch_Id = intvalue  --intvalue is used to get the latest batch_id to filter the data to the last completed batch process.  I will likely turn the select into a table value function to take a parameter that gets a different batch id called batch run id to filter for only those rows that are from the latest batch run and are of a particular batch type.
```

What I would like to see as a result set is:

```
Name       Version   VersionName    XYZABC_Content     ABCXYZ_Content    567ABC_Content
12.34.xxx    3.4       XYZABC       longdatastring           NULL                NULL
12.34.xyy    4.1       ABCXYZ            NULL         differentlongdatastring    NULL
12.34.xyx    3.4       567ABC            NULL                NULL    yetanotherdatastring
```

when the first WHEN clause of the first case expression is true and the second WHEN clause is false XYZABC_Content is populated
and when the first WHEN clause is false and the second WHEN clause is true the second row of this table would be the result and when the second CASE expressions WHEN clause was true the third row would be the result.

What I am getting is:

```
Name       Version   VersionName    XYZABC_Content ABCXYZ_Content 567ABC_Content   
12.34.xxx     3.4         XYZABC     longdatastring     NULL         NULL           
12.34.xyy     3.1         ABCXYZ             NULL       NULL         NULL     
12.34.xyx     3.4         567ABC             NULL       NULL         NULL
```

Regardless of which when expression is true and for each likewise treated column in the chain the values of those columns are also NULL until the cycle begins repeating by changing the secondary field (aka fieldn+1)

I have PURPOSEFULLY Anonymized the data as the data in the resultset is irrelevant as long as the correct column mappings can occur.  There is a "hidden" field called Content between the VersionName and the first conditionally formatted Content column (XYZABC_Content) that holds the data that should occur exclusively in one of the three _Content fields based on the CASE WHEN THEN logic.

Comment: You've anonymized your data so much that it doesn't make sense anymore. The output of all of your `CASE` expressions are the same. There is no data listed to validate business rules. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Then, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question.

Comment: My first iteration using search CASE expressions was correct.  The reason my query did not return expected results is attributable to `VersionName` column having an unexpected data error (in my case the error was from source data and that source data value was misspelled.  Commerical vs. Commercial  Exact matching of the string would always fall to NULL as the data and the search string value were different).

Answer (score 0):

The example above actually works if the compared string value and the value in the incoming dataset match.  The reason my results were skewed by NULLS was that one of the values of the comparison column `VersionName` was misspelled in the data (in the instant case the value expected was `VersionName = Commercial or Open Source Software` the value actually received was `VersionName = Commerical or Open Source Software`).  When I corrected my comparison string value to match that of the data the correct columns were populated.